# can't use apidoc with reverse proxy in nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a test server and try to serve [apidoc](https://blog.jscrambler.com/documenting-apis-using-apidoc-js/) on node.js with a reverse proxy but in the browser I see a empty page.

apidoc serves with [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) on port 3034 in node.js and I run it with pm2 and this is my default configuration in site-available

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location /docs {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3034;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

}